# Mobile Page Full-width - Centering Text with Icon

Tags: html, css

I don't know why I'm struggling with what seems to be such a simple thing. Right now I have a mobile page (which can also be viewed on desktop) which is using a full-width layout.

Inside it, I'd just like to center my text (of indeterminable size) and an icon that is 30x30 px.

```
<div id="contact-info">
    <div class="email">
        <div class="icon-left">
            <img src="image/mobile/message-dark.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-right">
            myverylongemailmyverylongemail@gmail.com
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the e-mail grows longer on the right, I'd like the  to increase in width but the whole thing stays centered.

```
#contact-info {
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #F7F8F8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#contact-info .email {
    height: 48px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact-info .icon-left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#contact-info .icon-left img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#contact-info .info-right {
    min-width: 240px;
    height: 50%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flexible box technique is best suited for your solution. Not need to define the fixed width for it using this method.

Check the browser compatibility table for [**Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
#contact-info {
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #F7F8F8;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#contact-info .email {
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#contact-info .icon-left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#contact-info .icon-left img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#contact-info .info-right {
  min-width: 240px;
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-info">
  <div class="email">
    <div class="icon-left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    </div>
    <div class="info-right">
      myverylongemailmyverylongemail@gmail.com another 
email@gmail.com 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip. However, while this solution works fine on my Note 2 (Android) on both Firefox and Chrome. It does not work on my bosses phone (Huawei). I can't find many answers to this. Do you know if prefixing will help?

Comment: Oh I see. Which browser is your boss using?

Comment: Not sure what it's called but it's the Huawei built-in web browser.

Comment: Sorry but Flexbox technique is supported in modern browsers(which really matter) :)